# Azure DevOps multi artifacts in the same release pipeline how to Prevent downloading all artifacts just the one who have a new release version

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Using Azure DevOps Version **Dev17**.M153.5

[image]

**Note** I have multi projects in the same solution.

### In Builds pipeline:

Every project has its own **build pipeline** with the help of Path filters I make triggers.

For example this 2 builds:

[image]

### Now in the Releases pipeline:

I add those builds as artifacts

[image]

in Continuous deployment trigger I enabled Build branch filters

Now if any of this build triggered the Stage will working automaticly
th issue is its download all the artifacts to the $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
in folder "_work\r1\a"

[image]

in this case i can't know which one it have the new version

the aim here is create one release pipeline for all build pipelines

all I need is to differentiate between the builds which one is raising the trigger at least.
I can't go with creating a release pipeline for every build pipeline because I have 40 projects in the same solution, imagine that I create dev, stage, prepord, and prod release pipeline for every project we will end up with 160 release pipelines, which is not applicable

### So

how to prevent downloading all artifacts at once like this
Or
have a way to know which one rise the trigger in the release pipeline

[image]

my release pipeline look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be solve by using Group variable and change one of the variable with the name of the current build info.
Then in release pipeline check this group variable and you will know the build name there.

```
- powershell: |
      $url = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/tfs/DefaultCollection/{yourTFSprojectName}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/2?api-version=5.0-preview.1"
      $json = '{"id":1,"type":"Vsts","name":"GroupName","variables":{"VarNmae":{"isSecret":false,"value":"valu123"}}}'
      $pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN")}
      Write-Host "New Variable Value:" $pipeline.variables.VarNmae.value
  displayName: PowerShellScript
  env:
     SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Comment: put this is just temp solution